# Get Cover Pic from Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, cover

I'm looking how to the the cover pic from Facebook using the Facebook SDK.
I think it's using a JSON method but I really don't know how to do it.

I tried using

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = user.getInnerJSONObject();
```

and this

```
URL url = new URL(my_url);
JSONObject obj = url.getContent();
```

I got the profile pic but now I need to get the cover pic.

Answer (score 1):

For the request:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=cover&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN

JSON response:

```
{
  "cover": {
    "id": "XXXXXXXXX", 
    "source": "URL_OF_COVER_PHOTO_IMAGE", 
    "offset_y": 50
  }, 
  "id": "XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Hope it helps you

To parse as JSON content use this class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        //add parameters to the post request

        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf8");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

Then you'll have the response as a JSON string. With JSONObject you'll be able to get only the field you want (the one with the cover url). Once you've the link, just download the bitmap from the url and show it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I saw that on Facebook's website but i don't know how to save that on a JSON Object. I mean, i've got problems to use URL's function to get the content of Facebook's answer.

Comment: @JorgeBrage look at my edit above. Hope this helps, let me know your thoughts.